# python class factory inherit random parent

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, factory

I have some code like this:

```
class Person(object):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        raise NotImplementedError

class John(Person):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        print "John drove from %s to %s" % (f,t)

class Kyle(Person):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        print "Kyle drove from %s to %s" % (f,t)

class RandomPerson(Person):
    # instansiate either John or Kyle, and inherit it.
    pass

class Vehicle(object):
    pass

class Driver(Person, Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        # instantiate and inherit a RandomPerson somehow
        pass

d1 = Driver()
d1.drive('New York', 'Boston')
>>> "John drove from New York to Boston"

d2 = Driver()
d2.drive('New Jersey', 'Boston')
>>> "Kyle drove from New Jersey to Boston"
```

How could i implement RandomPerson, with the following requirements:

- calling `person = RandomPerson()` must return a `RandomPerson` object.
- `RandomPerson` should subclass either `John` or `Kyle` randomly.

Comment: To inherit from a random class, though possible in Python, doesn't seem a very straightforward solution to your problem. I'd go with a factory function that randomly instantiates  one of your person classes and returns that instance, e.g. by picking the class randomly from a list of classes. The call to the factory function would look just like your RandomPerson constructor call.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with your actual question, but why do you have separate `John` and `Kyle` objects?  The names John & Kyle are attributes of a `Person` (just like height/weight/hair color/eye color, etc).

Comment: @jacdeh to me is sounds like a homework question that has been badly communicated (either by the prof or the OP).

Comment: This isn't homework, and i know the example looks like bad coding practice, but it's not. I was wondering if it can be done pythonic.

Comment: @user37203 Why does `RandomPerson` have to be a subclass of `John` or `Kyle`? Are you using `isinstance` or `issubclass`, or do you just want to make sure all of the `Kyle` or `John` methods are available to `RandomPerson` objects?

Comment: `RandomPerson` must have all the `Kyle` or `John` methods available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my original answer (which I deleted because it was just plain wrong) I said I would consider doing it like this:

```
class RandomPerson(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        rand_person = random.choice((John, Kyle))()
        self.__dict__ = rand_person.__dict__
```

This way is an adaptation of the Python [Borg idiom](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/); the idea was that everything that matters about an object is contained in its `__dict__`.

However, this only works when overwriting objects of the *same class* (which is what you are doing in the Borg idiom); the object `__dict__` only contains state information pertaining to object instance, **not** the object class.

It *is* possible to switch out the class of an object like so:

```
class RandomPerson(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        rand_person = random.choice((John, Kyle))
        self.__class__ = rand_person
```

However, doing it this way would mean that the call to `RandomPerson` would then not return an instance of `RandomPerson` per your requirement, but of `Kyle` or of `John`. So this is a no go.

Here is a way to get a `RandomPerson` object that *acts* like `Kyle` or `John`, but *isn't*:

```
class RandomPerson(Person): 
    def __new__(cls):
        new = super().__new__(cls)
        new.__dict__.update(random.choice((Kyle,John)).__dict__)
        return new
```

This one - very similar to the Borg idiom, except doing it with classes instead of instance objects and we're only copying the *current version* of the chosen class dict - is really pretty evil: we have lobotomized the `RandomPerson` class and (randomly) stuck the brains of a `Kyle` or `John` class in place. And there is no indication, unfortunately, that this happened:

```
>>> rperson = RandomPerson()
>>> assert isinstance(rperson,Kyle) or isinstance(rperson,John)
AssertionError
```

So we *still* haven't really subclassed `Kyle` or `John`. Also, this is really really evil. So please don't do it unless you have a really good reason.

Now, assuming you do in fact have a good reason, the above solution **should be good enough** if all you are after is making sure you can use any class state information (methods and class attributes) from `Kyle` or `John` with `RandomPerson`. However, as illustrated prior, `RandomPerson` still isn't a true subclass of either.

Near as I can tell there is no way to actually randomly subclass an object's class at instance creation AND to have the class maintain state across multiple instance creations. You're going to have to fake it.

One way to fake it is to allow `RandomPerson` to be considered a subclass of `John` and `Kyle` using the [abstract baseclass module and `__subclasshook__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), and adding that to your `Person` class. This looks like it will be a good solution since the `Person` class is an interface and isn't going to be directly used, anyway.

Here's a way to do that:

```
class Person(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    def drive(self, f, t):
        raise NotImplementedError
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if C.identity is cls:
            return True
        return NotImplemented

class John(Person):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        print "John drove from %s to %s" % (f,t)

class Kyle(Person):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        print "Kyle drove from %s to %s" % (f,t)

class RandomPerson(Person): 
    identity = None
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.identity = random.choice((John,Kyle))
        new = super().__new__(cls)
        new.__dict__.update(cls.identity.__dict__)
        return new

>>> type(RandomPerson())
class RandomPerson
>>> rperson = RandomPerson()
>>> isinstance(rperson,John) or isinstance(rperson,Kyle)
True
```

Now `RandomPerson` - though it technically is not a subclass - is *considered to be* a subclass of `Kyle` or `John`, and it also shares the *state* of `Kyle` or `John`. In fact, it will switch back and forth between the two, randomly, every time a new instance is created (or when `RandomPerson.identity` is changed). Another effect of doing things this way: if you have multiple `RandomPerson` instances, **they all *share* the state of whatever `RandomPerson` happens to be** in that moment -- i.e., `rperson1` might start out being `Kyle`, and then when `rperson2` is instantiated, both `rperson2` AND `rperson1` could be `John` (or they could both be `Kyle` and then switch to `John` when `rperson3` is created).

Needless to say, this is pretty weird behavior. In fact it is so weird, my suspicion is that your design needs a complete overhaul. I really don't think there is a very good reason to EVER do this (other than maybe playing a bad joke on someone).

If you don't want to mix this behavior into your `Person` class, you could also do it separately:

```
class Person(object):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        raise NotImplementedError

class RandomPersonABC():
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if C.identity is cls:
            return True
        return NotImplemented

class John(Person, RandomPersonABC):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        print "John drove from %s to %s" % (f,t)

class Kyle(Person, RandomPersonABC):
    def drive(self, f, t):
        print "Kyle drove from %s to %s" % (f,t)

class RandomPerson(Person): 
    identity = None
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.identity = random.choice((John,Kyle))
        new = super().__new__(cls)
        new.__dict__.update(cls.identity.__dict__)
        return new
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with changing the class of the object, like you pointed out: `rand_person = random.choice((John, Kyle))` and `self.__class__ = rand_person`. I've moved the methods of `RandomPerson` back into `Person`, and `RandomPerson` works now like a factory-ish generating class. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You could just implement the `RandomPerson` class to have a member called `_my_driver` or whatever else you wanted.  You would just call their `drive` method from the `RandomPerson.drive` method.  It could look something like this:

```
    class RandomPerson(Person):
    # instantiate either John or Kyle, and inherit it.
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_person = John() if random.random() > 0.50 else Kyle()
    def drive(self, f, t):
        self._my_person.drive(f,t)
```

Alternatively, if you want to be more strict about making sure that the class has exactly the same methods as `Kyle` or `John`, you could set the method in the constructor like the following:

```
class RandomPerson(Person):
    # instantiate either John or Kyle, and inherit it.
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_person = John() if random.random() > 0.50 else Kyle()
        self.drive = self._my_person.drive
```

Comment: What is the point of having `RandomPerson` inherit `Person`, if it has a `_my_person` attribute? The inheritance becomes pointless. Also, the `drive` function is different in the two `Kyle` and `John` classes, and more so, drive references other functions that are custom to `John` and `Kyle`.

Answer (score 0):

In your [most recent comment on my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899499/python-class-factory-inherit-random-parent/30902949#comment49862087_30902949) you said:

> I'm gonna go with changing the class of the object, like you pointed out: `rand_person = random.choice((John, Kyle))` and `self.__class__ = rand_person`. I've moved the methods of `RandomPerson` back into `Person`, and `RandomPerson` works now like a factory-ish generating class.

If I may say so, this is an odd choice. First of all, swapping out the class after object creation doesn't seem very pythonic (it's overly complicated). It would be better to generate the object instance randomly instead of assigning the class after the fact:

```
class RandomPerson(): # Doing it this way, you also don't need to inherit from Person
    def __new__(self):
        return random.choice((Kyle,John))()
```

Secondly, if the code has been refactored so that you no longer require a `RandomPerson` object, why have one at all? Just use a factory function:

```
def RandomPerson():
    return random.choice((Kyle,John))()
```

Comment: Well `RandomPerson` is inherited later by other classes, and i need it to be reliable and containerized.. usable anywhere. The names of the classes and the examples seem stupid, but i've worked it on paper and there is no other way for my real problem. I need to inherit a `RandomPerson`, not a `Person` which gets transformed into something else (into a `John` or `Kyle`). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You may want to look a little deeper into the benefits of abstract baseclasses. This kind of thing is what they were created for. Another thing to think about: "transforming" one object into another object seems like something that should be done explicitly, not magically/in the background. Consider doing it via a method - e.g. `RandomPerson().get_real_person()`  - or something.